# How can $\frac12 \log(x) = \log(\sqrt{x})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How can $\frac{\log (x)}{2}= \log \left(\sqrt{x}\right) \\$?

How would I come to this conclusion?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Proof

Comment: If $\mathrm{e}^y = √x$, then $\mathrm{e}^{2y} = (\mathrm{e}^y)^2 = x$ and so $2\log √x = \log x$. This implictly uses $\exp (a + b) = \exp a · \exp b$ which is equivalent to saying $\log x +  \log y = \log xy$ if one defines $\log = \exp^{-1}$, setting $x = \exp a$ and $y = \exp b$. But by this, you directly get $\log x^z = z \log x$ for $z ∈ ℤ$, which algebraically extends to $z ∈ ℚ$ and by continuity extends to $z ∈ ℝ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the rules?

$$ A \log (x) = \log (x^A) $$

With $A = \frac{1}{2}$, we obtain what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes of course, don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: that's not an explanation, that's a repetition of OP's claim.

Comment: Or best way if you didn't know that rule apply make the terms exponent of $e$ and then take log again.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that you know $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$. Then
$$
\log x=\log(\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x})=\log\sqrt{x}+\log\sqrt{x}=2\log\sqrt{x}
$$
and so
$$
\log\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{2}\log x.
$$
Anyway, it's just a special case of the general law
$$
\log(x^k)=k\log x
$$
(for $x>0$ and any $k$).

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle\log_bx=a, b^a=x$

If $\displaystyle\log_b(x^m)=c, x^m=b^c$

$\implies b^c=x^m=(b^a)^m\implies b^c=b^{am}$

$\displaystyle\iff b^{c-am}=1=b^0$ if $b\ne\pm1,0$

$\displaystyle\implies c-am=0$ if real $b\ne\pm1,0$

Replace the values of $a,c$

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you should know that this is a direct result of the [Logarithms of Powers Rule](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Logarithms_of_Powers):
$$\Large\log(\sqrt{x}) = \log(x^{1/2}) = \frac{1}{2} \log(x)$$

---

Here's my attempt at a proof nonetheless,

**To Prove**: $ \frac{1}{2} \log(x) = \log(\sqrt{x})$

**Proof**: Let us assume that the base of the logarithm is $b$.

We know that $x = b^{\log x} \implies \sqrt{x} =  b^{\log \sqrt{x}}$
$$
\Rightarrow x = b^{2\log \sqrt{x}} \\ 
\Rightarrow b^{\log x} = b^{2\log \sqrt{x}} \\ 
\Rightarrow \log(x) = 2\log(\sqrt{x}) \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \log(x) = \log(\sqrt{x})
$$

---

**Aliter**: 
$$\large\frac{1}{2} \log(x) = \log(\sqrt{x}) \Leftrightarrow \log(x) = 2\log(\sqrt{x}) \Leftrightarrow x = b^{2\log(\sqrt{x})}$$

$$
\large\text{RHS} = b^{\log(\sqrt{x}) + \log(\sqrt{x})}
=  b^{\log(\sqrt{x})} \times b^{\log(\sqrt{x})}
= \sqrt{x} \times \sqrt{x} = x = \text{LHS}$$

Comment: This is not a valid proof. You begin by assuming that which you are trying to prove! If you want to show that $\log(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{1}{2}\log(x)$ you can't begin by assuming that to be true.

Comment: @SimonRose: Yes I can. That's how most proof by contradiction's start out. In my case, there was no contradiction and therfore I verified what I had :D

Comment: That's not correct. If a contradiction were to arise then yes, you'd have proven that your premise was false. But the lack of contradiction doesn't make your statement true! It just means that it is not contradictory. If I assume a false statement and use it to derive a true fact (which one can always do), then this does not mean that the initial false statement is true!

Comment: ` But the lack of contradiction doesn't make your statement true!` . Now what exactly am I supposed to do? Delete my answer? Can you tell me what I need to add inorder to make it right?

Comment: With "proofs" like this, very often the reason that the correct answer is still obtained is because each statement $\implies$ is in fact an $\Leftrightarrow$ i.e. an equivalence. So in your case it is valid to say:

$\frac{1}{2}\log x = \log\sqrt{x} \Leftrightarrow \log x = 2\log \sqrt{x} \Leftrightarrow x = b^{2\log\sqrt{x}} = (b^{\log\sqrt{x}})^2 = (\sqrt{x})^2 = x$.

Since this latter statement is true, then each of the statments equivalent to it is also true. QED.